# How do I `findByPk` when the primary key's type is date?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have a model who's primary key `date` is defined as type `DataTypes.DATE`.
(It's `defaultValue` is `DataTypes.NOW`)

At some point I create an instance like so:

```js
const inst = await model.create({/* ... */});
```

later I do some modifications and associations on it,
and then I want to `findByPk` the same instance after the changes. What I tried is:

```js
const dbInst = await model.findByPk(inst.date)
```

but I get the following error:

> Argument passed to findByPk is invalid: Fri Aug 14 2020 16:52:23 GMT+0300 (Israel Daylight Time)

Looks like it doesn't like being passed a `Date` object.

Comment: a workaround is to use `findOne` instead of `findByPk`, but that's less optimal

Comment: Can you try `findByPk(inst.date.toISOString())`?

Comment: In SQLite that works, @Emma